# Java object set chain command

Tags: java, object, syntax, chain

Is there a plugin or a tool you can use to simply add this method to the Object class in java?

```
public this set(Object o){
    this = o;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: You can't (and certainly don't want to) add methods to classes, and this isn't even valid Java code. So I guess the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting code into the Object class actually is the smaller problem (although personally, I won't help you finding a solution - if one exists), the content of your `set()` method is really, seriously impossible in Java.

You simply cannot assign to `this`. And no tool whatsoever will change that.

A given instance of a Java class will keep its identity over all its lifetime. Changing that would need a conceptually different Java Virtual Machine.

With the `set()` method you ask for, it would become possible to change e.g. a `String` to a `Date`, making all code using that object as a `String` fail. Because after the change, the object no longer has methods like `indexOf()`, but instead things like `before()` or `getTime()`.

So, you have to look for a different solution to the problem you want to address with your proposed `set()` method.

Let me suggest you decribe the use case for your set() method, so we can help you find a solution.